# PyCharm integrated RegExp discrepancy

Tags: python, regex, pycharm

I am using PyCharm Community Edition 3.4, using Python version 3.4.1
When running the following code:

```
regex2 = re.compile('\p{P}')

if regex2.match('.'):
    print("success")
else:
    print("fail")
```

It prints fail. The \p{P} construct is supposed to match punctuation - and that's what it does when using the "Check RegExp" functionality of PyCharm.

Before using \p{P}, I tried to match to String.punctuation instead, but that would lead to

> sre_constants.error: multiple repeat

A fix for any of those two would be much appreciated.

edit: Or any alternative for matching punctuation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The re module does not support unicode character classes like `\p{P}`. To use them, use the [new regex module.](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex)

```
import regex

regex2 = regex.compile(r'\p{P}')

if regex2.match('.'):
    print("success")
else:
    print("fail")
```

Comment: Looks promising, trying it out now.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. Installing regex is a bit of a pain in windows, but at least it now works.

Comment: @ArneRecknagel: If you read carefully the documentation, you will notice that it is a no limit module.

Comment: What does 'no limit' mean?